# Where to place my code to select first option of <select> with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I need to select first option of select with jQuery. My code is a bit complex and can't figure out how to make it work. Thanks

Html:

```
'sortingHtml': '<select id="bc-sf-filter-top-sorting-select">{{sortingItems}}</select>'
```

Javascript:

```
BCSfFilter.prototype.buildFilterSorting = function() {
  if (bcSfFilterTemplate.hasOwnProperty('sortingHtml')) {

    jQ(this.selector.topSorting).html('');

    var sortingArr = this.getSortingList();

    if (sortingArr) {
      // Build content
      var sortingItemsHtml = '';
      for (var k in sortingArr) {
        sortingItemsHtml += '<option value="' + k +'">' + sortingArr[k] + '</option>';
      }
      sortingItemsHtml = '<option disabled="disabled" selected>Sort by</option>' + sortingItemsHtml

      var html = bcSfFilterTemplate.sortingHtml.replace(/{{sortingItems}}/g, sortingItemsHtml);
      jQ(this.selector.topSorting).html(html);

      // Set current value
      jQ(this.selector.topSorting + ' select').val(this.queryParams.sort);
    }
  }
};
```

Code to select the first option:

```
$("#bc-sf-filter-top-sorting-select").val($("#bc-sf-filter-top-sorting-select option:first").val());
```

Comment: *"My code is a bit complex and can't figure out how to make it work."* I think you copied the code incorrectly.

Comment: It's the right code @zer00ne.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#bc-sf-filter-top-sorting-select option:first").prop("selected", true);
```

Comment: thanks Yahya Khalil. Any idea where to place the code though? That's the part I'm having difficulties with. If I add it after jQ(this.selector.topSorting + ' select').val(this.queryParams.sort); it keeps the first option value selected even after selecting a different option.

Comment: While this answer might resolve the OP's question, it is suggested that you explain how it works and why it resolves the issue. This helps new developers understand what is going on and how to fix this and similar issues themselves. Thanks for contributing!

Comment: you can add some condition before this statement to ensure executing it once.
or using flag to detect that change event had occurred to not set it to first option again.